# How to initialize Widgets in initState() that comes from a Stream and should be realtime updated

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Hello together for my project i need the package reorderables. => https://pub.dev/packages/reorderables/example
to create a reorderable Row i have to initialize the Widgets of the row in the initState() method.

The thing is, the app should be updated in Realtime when data is changing in Firebase. So I have to use StreamBuilder.
How can I initialize the Widget in initState() when I don't have the snapshot of the data when the app starts?

With FutureBuilder i manage to do this by initializing the Widgets as `Future<List<Widget>>` and awaiting the data. It works perfect but I need Realtime updates and I have no Idea how to do it with StreamBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution. I just will pass the AsyncSnapshot to an instance variable a new Stateful Widget and then I can use it in initState. :)